# I want to interpolate the values inside one column. Using Matlab

Tags: matlab

The matrix looks like this:

```
0   0
0.1 0
0.2 0 
0.3 5
0.4 0
0.5 0
0   0
0.1 0
0.2 6
0.3 0 
0.4 0
0.5 0
```

As you can see it is a simple matrix (x,y), all i want is to linearly interpolate the values of column 2. How can i do that ?

Comment: Look at this: `interp1` or `spline`

Comment: I does not seems to make sense ... Your first column is not monotonic and   second column has different values for same "positions" in first column ... could you please reformulate your question? ... what is the 'abscissa' axis and at which new positions do you want to interpolate second column ? You may also directly read matlab documentation for 1D data interpolation: http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`interp1`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) with `linear` and `extrap` option

```
%// Taking only the non-zero rows
B = A(all(A,2),:)

%// performing linear interpolation on first column of 'A' with 'interp1'
out = interp1(B(:,1),B(:,2),A(:,1),'linear','extrap')
```

**Results:**

```
B =

0.3000    5.0000
0.2000    6.0000

out =

8.0000
7.0000
6.0000
5.0000
4.0000
3.0000
8.0000
7.0000
6.0000
5.0000
4.0000
3.0000
```

If you want them with `x` values

```
out = [A(:,1),out]
```

You get

```
out =

     0    8.0000
0.1000    7.0000
0.2000    6.0000
0.3000    5.0000
0.4000    4.0000
0.5000    3.0000
     0    8.0000
0.1000    7.0000
0.2000    6.0000
0.3000    5.0000
0.4000    4.0000
0.5000    3.0000
```

Comment: Nice interpretation of the question ... :)

Comment: Can you please, explain this part:
interp1(B(:,1),B(:,2),A(:,1)

Comment: @user3049408 sure. if you look at the documentation (hyperlink provided), 1st and the 2nd arguments corresponds to the known `x` and `y` values. third argument is the `x` values for which you want the corresponding `y` values. Does this make you clear? Try to print them separately in command prompt. It will make you understand better.

Comment: Thank you, i figured it out.